# "Remesh" modifier hides my text object

Tags: modifiers, text-object

At first, I had a simple text object:
[image: Screenshot showing my text object 'Text']

Then I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and selected `Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text` in order to convert the text object into a mesh.

Now I want to apply the *Remesh* modifier, however, it hides my text in normal mode and in the rendered image (it is visible in the edit mode though!).

Screenshot (normal mode):
[image: Normal mode after having selected the Remesh modifier]

Screenshot (edit mode):
[image: Edit mode after having selected the Remesh modifier]

Why is my object invisible in the normal mode and when I render it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Remesh modifier doesn't seem to work on flat objects so you need to give your text some volume/thickness.

In edit mode select all the faces and press <kbd>E</kbd> and extrude the text a little to give it some volume.

The Remesh modifier will now work but will remove all but one letter of the text until 'Remove Disconnected Pieces' is unchecked on the Remesh modifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Apart from your solution, setting the *"Extrude"* value to `0.001` on the `F (Text)` tab before converting to a mesh also works.

Answer (score 4):

The remesh modifier tries to divide the volume of an object into a bunch of cubes and create new vertices where the edges of the cubes cross the original mesh. This only works if the mesh has a volume. Thus you need to either extrude the mesh or increase the "Extrude" value of the text before you convert it into a mesh.

[image]

You should also disable "Remove Disconnected Pieces" in the modifier and increase the "Octree Depth" value. This value defines how small the cubes used for the remeshing will be. But be careful, don't set it too high. The number of cubes increase with two to the power of octree depth times three. A value of 6 should be enough.